# How to Serialize a NSCFArray (possible JSON) to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, foursquare

I'm really stuck right now while using BZForursquare to get nearby Venues into a UITableView.

BZFoursquare: https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api

I get my Requestresult inside the requestDidFinishLoading Delegate Method. In this Method the request Object contains several NSDictionaries and one Dictionary is in request.response. This response Dictionary contains one entry with key="venues" and as Value a JSON Object. When I put this value Object into a dictionary the type seems not to be a Dictionary but a NSCFArray:

```
#pragma mark BZFoursquareRequestDelegate
- (void)requestDidFinishLoading:(BZFoursquareRequest *)request {
    self.meta = request.meta;
    self.notifications = request.notifications;
    self.response = [request.response objectForKey:@"venues"];
    self.request = nil;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.response objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

I assume this because the NSLog Line gives me the following error:

-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e5c90f0

Now I'm totaly confused and tried some failed attempts to get this JSON from whatever kind od Datatype it is into a NSDictionary. One attempt was to put the value Object into an NSString and use

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
```

to get it into a Dictionary but that also failed because it still remains a NSCFArray. Can someone please tell me how I get content of

```
[request.response objectForKey:@"venues"]
```

into a NSDictionary so that I can populate my UITabelview with this content?

EDIT:

Here is whats in the value part from the Dictionary request.response:

```
(
    {
    categories =         (
                    {
            icon =                 {
                name = ".png";
                prefix = "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/default_";
                sizes =                     (
                    32,
                    44,
                    64,
                    88,
                    256
                );
            };
            id = 4bf58dd8d48988d10b941735;
            name = "Falafel Restaurant";
            pluralName = "Falafel Restaurants";
            primary = 1;
            shortName = Falafel;
        }
    );
    contact =         {
    };
    hereNow =         {
        count = 0;
        groups =             (
        );
    };
    id = 4df3489dfa76abc3d86c4585;
    likes =         {
        count = 0;
        groups =             (
        );
    };
    location =         {
        cc = DE;
        city = "Vinn";
        country = Germany;
        distance = 92;
        lat = "51.44985";
        lng = "16.648693";
        state = "Nordrhein-Westfalen";
    };
    name = "Yildiz D\U00f6ner";
    specials =         (
    );
    stats =         {
        checkinsCount = 3;
        tipCount = 0;
        usersCount = 2;
    };
    verified = 0;
}
```

And this seems to be from Type of NSCFArray. And how can I create from this another Dictionary so that I can access the JSON Values by key? Sorry if I'm really slow today...

Comment: Could you please log the JSON you get back from the webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for "venues" which I assume is an array of such. So after deserializing the json, log the return object to see what you get. It's almost for sure an array of dictionaries.